# Simple flot graph not updating

Tags: graph, flot

I'm trying to create a simple flot line graph and update it on a timer and I only want to display the last 10 points of data. But I only ever see the axis and not the graph plot. Also, I see the x axis change with the extra data but the y axis remain the same and do not correspond to the additional data. My code is as following:

```
var dataSet = [];
var PlotData;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var plot = null;

function EveryOneSec()
{
    if (dataSet.length == 10)
    {
        dataSet.shift();
    }
    x++;
    y += 2;
    dataSet("[" + x + ", " + y + "]");

    PlotData = { label: "line 1", data: [ dataSet ], color: "green" };

    if (plot == null)
    {
        plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ PlotData ], { lines: {show: true}, points:          {show: true}});
    }
    else
    {
        plot.setData([ PlotData ]);
        plot.setupGrid();
        plot.draw();
    }
    setTimeout(EveryOneSec, 1000);
}
```

I have tried with and without the call to setupGrid() but this makes no difference to the axis display or graph plot. The x axis stop changing when I get the ticks 0 to 9 plotted even though x is incrementing past that, and the y axis remains static. I believe the code is correct above in terms of passing arrays of data, so why is the graph not appearing?

Answer (score 2):

OK, you have two problems here.

First, you're not appending to your `dataSet` correctly.  I'm not sure what the syntax you've got is doing, but what you need in each slot of the array is `[x,y]`, which you can achieve with `Array.push`.

This:

```
dataSet("[" + x + ", " + y + "]");
```

Should look like this:

```
dataSet.push([x , y]);
```

And when you create your series object `PlotData`, you don't need to store your data inside of another array, so instead of this:

```
PlotData = { label: "line 1", data: [ dataSet ], color: "green" };
```

You need this:

```
PlotData = { label: "line 1", data:  dataSet , color: "green" };
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/qJEXH/